# WinRT preload images

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 XAML app where I'd like to *preload* images before navigating between pages.

The naive code I have now is:

```cs
// Page1.xaml.cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
}
```

And on the second page:

```cs
// Page2.xaml.cs
this.image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/image1.jpg"));
this.image2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/image2.jpg"));
```

Now, when I click the button to navigate, I can see the images being loaded and showing up one at the time. I would like to pre-load the images on the button click and only navigate *after* the images have been loaded.

Unfortunately, just creating the `BitmapImage` objects and waiting for the `ImageOpened` events doesn't work. It appears that the images aren't loaded if they aren't rendered to the screen.

Is there a way to force loading of the images from code without adding them to the visual tree?

(Note: a workaround would be to actually add all the images to the Window in some invisible way, but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible)

---

**Final solution:**

This is what I've come up with using `SetSourceAsync`, as suggested by *Filip Skakun*:

```cs
// Page1.xaml.cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  bitmapImage1 = new BitmapImage();
  bitmapImage2 = new BitmapImage();

  // Load both images in parallel
  var task1 = loadImageAsync(bitmapImage1, "image1.jpg");
  var task2 = loadImageAsync(bitmapImage2, "image2.jpg");
  await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

  Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
}

private Task loadImageAsync(BitmapImage bitmapImage, string path)
{
  var filePath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\" + path;
  var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
  var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
  await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}
```

```cs
// Page2.xaml.cs
this.image1.Source = bitmapImage1;
this.image2.Source = bitmapImage2;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinRT XAML Toolkit's [`AlternativeFrame`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/AlternativeFrame/AlternativeFrame.cs) control and [`AlternativePage`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/AlternativeFrame/AlternativePage.cs) one have a `ShouldWaitForImagesToLoad` property that when you set to true and navigate to a page - will only display the page when the images have loaded. `AlternativePage` has a `Preload()` method you can also override to add more things to await before displaying the page. The way it is implemented though is the page is first added to an invisible container in the visual tree, so loading of those `BitmapImages` gets triggered.

Another option might be to use [`SetSourceAsync()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsourceasync.aspx) which you can await and I think it starts loading before you use the `BitmapImage` in the UI, but then you need to download the file yourself.

Comment: I don't just need this for page transitions, but in other places as well. So the AlternativePage isn't exactly what I need. But I did solve the issue using `SetSourceAsync`. Thanks!

Comment: One thing I'd often done is use the [`FrameworkElementExtensions.WaitForImagesToLoad`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/AwaitableUI/FrameworkElementExtensions.cs) method - to just wait for all `Image` sources to load inside of any visual tree.