# WinRT cache with cleanup on low memory

Tags: caching, windows-runtime, low-memory

I have a WinRT application which uses many (sometimes large) images. The images are stored on disk, but it takes some time to load the images, which causes a visual hiccup. To fix that, I [load the images beforehand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22771675/2597) and store them into a cache.

However, I'm a bit hesitant to store an arbitrary number for images in memory, and would like to use a cache that is automatically cleaned when memory gets low.

How would I go about implementing this? On iOS there is a `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method, but I can't find an equivalent method for WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

If using .NET you could try holding [weak references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to images in the cache and so when you use them - they won't be garbage collected, but if you don't - they will be collected when memory pressure occurs. When retrieving images from the cache - you'd simply check if the weak reference is alive and if it is not - you'd reload the image before returning.